# How to view source control changes on Linx

Tags: automation

I'm new to Linx. I'm struggling to find the changes I've made previously.

I have looked at the files but cannot open in a IDE, such as notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick way to view your changes in source control such as git or view the changes in a simple .txt doc. To view the changes you need to understand how linx stores is process.

The linx solution stores its formatting of the processes under the hood using in a SQL lite DB. In the DB it stores the parent and child process and what is going on. To view the changes effectively you would need to unzip the .bak file, load the SQL into a SQL lite db, query the data stored and then traverse the SQL tree and compare it the original process.

In Linx's current road map they plan to add the ability to view the differences in source control in a human readable format.